# How to input data on my website and get it submitted in another website automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having difficulties in copying a website that send free SMS, I will like to allow visitors to my site to send SMS for free so that they will keep coming to my site but i don't have fund to setup an SMS gateway but I was able to find a website that allow visitors to their website to send free SMS worldwide.

I will like to create the requested data on their website to be on mine site so that visitors on my site can send free SMS. it will look like the service is truly coming from my site without knowing that it is a copied service.

I will want php script to do this but i don't have an idea to do this but i was able to extract some codes from their site to mine and i try sending sms but it keep taking me to their site please can you please take a look at code below:

```html
[PHP]<div id="main">
  <div align="center">
        <h2>Send Free Online SMS Worldwide</h2>
        <br>
        <table align="center">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left"><big><span style="color: #45c7ee;">●</span></big></td>
    <td align="left"><strong>Send free online SMS</strong> (text messages) to any mobile phone in the <strong>world</strong>!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><big><span style="color: #45c7ee;">●</span></big></td>
    <td align="left"><strong>No registration required</strong>! Just write your message and send it.</td>
  </tr>
  
<tr>
    <td align="left"><big><span style="color: #45c7ee;">●</span></big></td>
    <td align="left"><strong>Once you send your first SMS (text message)</strong>!  wait for three minutes before sending another SMS.</td>
  </tr>
   <br>
<table align="center">
  <br>

<tbody><tr>
    <td align="left"><small><b>NOTE:</b> Abuse is strictly forbidden. This service is NOT anonymous.</small></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><small>We store all records and co-operate fully with the legal authorities to trace abusive messages to the originator.</small></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><small>Read the <a href="http://www.afrimefinc.co.uk/termofservice">Terms of Service</a> before you send your message.</small></td>
  </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    <form id="smsform" name="form85326947" action="http://www.e-freesms.com/sms.php" method="post">
        <table align="center">
  <tbody><tr>
   
<br>
<br><td align="left"><b>Select country:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><select name="country85326947" onchange="document.form85326947.countrycode85326947.value = document.form85326947.country85326947.options[document.form85326947.country85326947.selectedIndex].value" style="width: 200px;">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="1">USA ⁄ Canada</option>
<option value="" disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
<option value="93">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="355">Albania</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(recipient's country)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left"><b>Enter number:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">+<input name="countrycode85326947" maxlength="4" readonly="readonly" style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;<input name="number85326947"placeholder="Exclude leading zero"maxlength="20" style="width: 200px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(recipient's phone number)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Your message:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><label style="color: black; display: block;" id="limitlbl_0"><br>100 characters remaining</label><textarea limiterid="limitlbl_0" name="message85326947" placeholder="Free Texting by  www.afrimefinc.co.uk" maxlength="100" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td align="left"><b>Captcha code:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeEoxwTAAAAAE0JzeH5Ch7OxW4adQ6Fj145pwVj"></script>


    <br>
       
<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LeEoxwTAAAAAE0JzeH5Ch7OxW4adQ6Fj145pwVj" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
 </noscript></td>
  </tr>
        </table>
<br>        <input type="hidden" name="ne45byg98c" value="287w56t4h9d3aqxrkvcgsnb" />
        <input type="image" src="css/images/button-send.png" width="175" height="69" border="0" alt="SEND" />
        </form>
  <script src="js/charcount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        [/PHP]
```

The information requested before allowing one to send sms on their site are: 
1. country
2. number
3. message
4. captcha

The requested information i extracted only captcha didn't appear properly at my site but all other information was able to displayed but also can't send sms.

Some one ask me to try this codes below but i don't know where to start from I'm I to use the two codes as two script so as to upload it to my cpanel or what?

Please can any one help me explain it step by step guide on how I can do this with php please?

```html
output page(http://www.e-freesms.com/sms.php):

    <?php
    if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "post") {
    echo "your country: $_POST[Select_Country]";
    echo "the number: $_POST[Enter_Number]";
    echo "your message: $_POST[Your_Message]";
    echo "the captcha: $_POST[Captcha_code]";
    }
    ?>

 
Server-side    

<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "post") {
    echo "welcome $post[name] to my country!";
    } else {
    echo "welcome $get[name] to my country!";  }
    ?>
```

I look forward to hear from you guys.

Comment: Your freeloader business idea will suffer a sudden demise the moment the SMS provider notices what's going on and blocks traffic from your server's IP address or range. Better not waste any precious lifetime with code which will become obsolete within a week, but rather focus on developing your own legitimate service.